# Dynamic Body gets stuck in static body after flipping

Tags: c++, box2d, game-physics

I have a dynamic body with many polygon shapes for my game character. In order to turn back the game character I flip vertices using this code:

```
void Box2dManager::flipFixtures(bool horizzontally, b2Body* physBody)
{
    b2Fixture* fix = physBody->GetFixtureList();

    while(fix)
    {
        b2Shape* shape = fix->GetShape();
        if(shape->GetType()== b2Shape::e_polygon)
        {   
            // flipping x or y coordinates
            b2PolygonShape* ps = (b2PolygonShape*)shape;
            for(int i=0; i < ps->GetVertexCount(); i++)
                horizzontally ? ps->m_vertices[i].x *= -1 : ps->m_vertices[i].y *= -1;

            // revert the vertices (no need after Box2D 2.3.0 as polygon creation computes the convex hull)
            b2Vec2* reVert = new b2Vec2[ps->GetVertexCount()];
            int j = ps->GetVertexCount() -1;
            for(int i=0; i<ps->GetVertexCount();i++)
                reVert[i] = ps->m_vertices[j--];

            ps->Set(&reVert[0], ps->GetVertexCount());
        }
        fix = fix->GetNext();
    }
}
```

I also have static edge shapes as walls. And it happens, that when I flip the character, sometimes vertices of the same polygon appear to be in different sides of the same static edge shape. As a result my character sticks to the wall (it is being trapped in the static edge shape). How I should handle this situation?

Comment: Pretty sure that changing shape vertices on the fly isn't supported or at least advised against. Try removing the old shape, then create a new shape with the flipped vertices and assign it to the body. This may make Box2D aware of this change, and will hopefully have it resolve the collision by moving the body outside the collision.

Comment: `ps->Set(&reVert[0], ps->GetVertexCount());` is the same as delete all the shapes a create new shape with the given vertices. I have tried with not edge shape but with a rectangle. If the vertices are inside the body, box2d does  resolve the collision by moving the body outside the collision, but if vertices are in different sides, than this is again the same situation.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D I agree that changin vertices on the fly is not the best thing for Box2D, but in 2D game, sometimes you need the character to be able to turn back. How we should do this? There should be a common approach, right?

Comment: Well, the common approach would be to either make the collision shape identical for both directions, and where that isn't possible have two shapes or even two bodies for the player where you enable only the one for the direction the player is facing, and when turning around disable it and activate the other shape or body.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D if you have say a dinosaur with a long tale head is up tale is down, you can't make the collision shape identical for both directions. On the other hand, what is the difference between activating-deactivating the collider and removing the old one and creating a new one?

Comment: It's worth giving it a try. It might result in different behavior, or it might not.